# Changing Airlines in Spain - UK Citizen without Passport

Tags: schengen

My son's UK citizenship came through today, we're not applying for his UK passport from here (Bolivia) instead we're travelling to the Republic on his Bolivian passport and then we'll drive to Northern Ireland and apply for it when we get there.

We're now looking for flights, and there are no direct flights from anywhere in South America to Dublin. Therefore we're looking at a stopover in Spain.

My question is twofold: firstly Iberia have a flight all under them, which goes through Madrid, and is all within terminal 4 and 4s - would any visa be necessary in that case?

Secondly, if we were to change airlines, and therefore change terminals (from 4S to 2, in case it matters) would we need a schengen visa for that?

I know that Bolivia is NOT on the list of countries that need a transit visa, but as to whether this would be considered transit I'm super confused and the information is mixed online.

Thank you all!

Comment: What is your citizenship? When you say that your son's citizenship 'came through' today, do you mean that you have received written correspondance there in Bolivia that his application was approved? Your going to struggle to get an airline to allow your child to board without a proper travel document. Just being realistic.

Comment: Terms seems to be used interchangeably, however I believe that ‘Transit’ means you are landing to a point between the original departure airport and the final destination airport and continuing your travel with the same flight number. ‘Transfer’ means passengers who have a transit stop and who continue their travel with the same or different airline. In both cases the stop must usually be less than 24 hours. When traveling internationally, a stopover refers to a stay that lasts longer than 24 hours. Others may correct my understanding :-)

Comment: @ouflak If the OP is planning to drive from Dublin to N Ireland, as far as the airline is concerned the ROI is the final destination and the Bolivian passport will be enough to TWOV in Spain? https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: @Traveller... Maybe could work...

Comment: @ouflak I’m British, with a UK passport. He’s now Bolivian and British (received his Certificate of Registration) but he only holds a Bolivian passport. Therefore is his UK citizenship basically ignored as he doesn’t have a UK travel document?

Comment: @Traveller That is no my understanding.  To me, "transit" is where you stay airside while changing planes.

Comment: "the Republic" means "...of Ireland"?

Comment: Basically, if you need to go through passport control in Spain, you'll need a Schengen visa for your son to be able to board the plane.  Most Schengen airports are set up to avoid having to go through passport control to get from a non-Schengen arrival to a non-Schengen departure.  I don't know about Madrid, however.

Comment: If by some miracle the airline lets you on the plane and you find yourself needing to go though immigration control in Madrid, it should be possible either by showing a document attesting to your son's British citizenship or by showing his relationship to you (i.e., by invoking either his own right of free movement as a British citizen or his derivative right of free movement as the family member of a British citizen).

Comment: As a question about transit, though, this is probably a better fit for [Travel.SE].  But a similar question was posted there recently (arrival from Morocco, transfer to UK), so have a look around.

Comment: Note that even if you are legally OK, the airline might not let you check in...